# How to interpret time-ordering operator in Dyson series?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

To derive Dyson's Series, we use the fact that for every operator $V$, we have

$$\int_0^tdt_1\int_0^{t_1}dt_2\dots\int_0^{t_n}dt_nV(t_1)V(t_2)\dots V(t_n)= \frac{1}{n!}T\left(\left({\int_0^{t}dt'V(t')}\right)^n\right)$$

where $T$ is the time-ordering operator. This can be found e.g. [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_51F12_Ch5.pdf) on page 29

But how do we interpret the RHS of the equation $$T\left(\left({\int_0^{t}dt'V(t')}\right)^n\right)$$? If we evaluate $$\left({\int_0^{t}dt'V(t')}\right)^n$$ it is only dependent on one time variable $t$. What role would the operator $T$ then play?

Answer (score 2):

You act with the time-ordering operator *before* performing any integrals. For instance
\begin{align}
T \left( \int_0^t dt' V(t') \right)^2 &= \int_0^t dt' \int_0^t dt'' T ( V(t') V(t'')) \\
&= \int_0^t dt' \int_0^t dt'' \left[ V(t') V(t'') \theta(t'-t'') + V(t'') V(t') \theta(t''-t) \right]
\end{align}
In the second term, we can interchange $t' \leftrightarrow t''$ and it then equals the first term. It follows that
\begin{align}
T \left( \int_0^t dt' V(t') \right)^2 &= 2 \int_0^t dt' \int_0^{t'} dt''   V(t') V(t'') .
\end{align}
I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I see your point, thanks! But then how is the compact form of the interaction picture with dependent Hamiltonian helpful at all?

Comment: If you keep on reading, you will see how time-ordering of local operators can be related to normal ordering via Wick contraction. Further, Wick contractions simplify to the Feynman propagator so this gives a simple way of doing a perturbative expansion in QFT. Also, inside time-ordering, all operators commute so that's a bonus. Finally, the path integral in QFT directly gives us a time-ordered product as well so in fact, the time-ordered product is the EASIEST thing to calculate in a quantum theory.